# RSA Encryption in Java: IllegalBlockSizeException

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, keystore

I am trying to set up RSA Encryption in my Java project. I generated an asymmetric key with the following command in the Terminal:

`keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias mykey -keystore mykey.jks -storepass mykeypass -keypass mykeypass`

Now I load the keystore with the following method:

```
public void loadKeyStore() throws KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException, 
NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEY_TYPE);
    char[] storePwdArray = STORE_PASS.toCharArray();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(KEY_STORE_PATH);
    keyStore.load(fis, storePwdArray);
}
```

Now, I have two methods, one for encryption, one for decryption:

```
public String encrypt(String data) throws CertificateException, KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    if (keyStore == null) {
        loadKeyStore();
    }
    Certificate cert = keyStore.getCertificate(ALIAS);
    Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    rsa.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, cert.getPublicKey());
    byte[] encryptedBytes = rsa.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedBytes);
}

public String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws UnrecoverableKeyException, CertificateException, KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchPaddingException {
    if (keyStore == null) {
        loadKeyStore();
    }
    Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    char[] keyPwdArray = KEY_PASS.toCharArray();
    Key key = keyStore.getKey(ALIAS, keyPwdArray);
    rsa.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decryptedBytes = rsa.doFinal(encryptedData.getBytes());
    return new String(decryptedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

In the main method I try to encrypt and decrypt a String and print it, like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, CertificateException, KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    RSAEncryptionService encryptionService = new RSAEncryptionService();
    String secretMessage = "Hello World!";
    String encryptedMessage = encryptionService.encrypt(secretMessage);
    System.out.println(encryptedMessage);
    String decryptedMessage = encryptionService.decrypt(encryptedMessage);
    System.out.println(decryptedMessage);
}
```

The encryption works fine and returns something like that: `B61g7zzXDNW9AO/Idc/OBZOCDOJpQTwgchD9uJisEBgxy8HV1XPYZZaLEnxkJHed2sBAQXEIyCDcIAHWk5rxn40tVd4NwlIUya1rB6WNvRFLrrN30G7VjMU6NNUdwJ55n7is2Ylfu0SkwNpy/o4e9LaZyzCyr4lJsTbFEXJQJKqLsOC+ysHYdhzx61Y8UJw6mUhleju7h11OcdDBdGEtAtBcKx9WDt2cgHrdtYUgUkwmEy3vTuuyUwVVpjA4QwUsjXnN+i19FQBZt67sMYIpUT4x4yJ8egqN4mJ2N8aNLwF7m/FS7EZphXdna4KN0srKBbPquB1ER5be6RnoyMFDsg==`

But when it comes to the decryption, I get the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 256 bytes
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:349)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:406)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2205)
```

What I tried:

I read somewhere on StackOverflow that I need to increase the size of the key. But, that also produces a longer encrypted String, and then the Exception just states "Data must not be longer than 512/1024/... bytes".

I tried using a KeyPair generated in Code, like below. That worked, but I have no idea how to get that KeyPair into my keystore.

```
public void initKeyStore() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, KeyStoreException, IOException, CertificateException {
    KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    generator.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
    Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pair.getPublic());
    byte[] secretMessageBytes = "secretMessage".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] encryptedMessageBytes = encryptCipher.doFinal(secretMessageBytes);
    String encodedMessage = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedMessageBytes);
    System.out.println(encodedMessage);

    Cipher decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pair.getPrivate());
    byte[] decryptedMessageBytes = decryptCipher.doFinal(encryptedMessageBytes);
    String decryptedMessage = new String(decryptedMessageBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println(decryptedMessage);
}
```

Comment: On encryption sode you are encoding the ciphertext with Base64 to a readable string ("return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedBytes);") but this extends the ciphertext and on when trying to decrypt the data you get the error. The solution is easy - just **decode** the ciphertext **string** (using Base64 decoder) to a byte array. As already answered by @Afshin you should think about about a **hybrid encryption scheme** for encryption of larger data.

Comment: Please consider that using RSA has many security pitfalls: **[Seriously, stop using RSA](https://blog.trailofbits.com/2019/07/08/fuck-rsa/)**

Comment: @Robert [RSA can survive CQC but ECC not easily](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59600/18298). RSA is the most used both for public-key encryption and digital signature therefore the attacks are twofold.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple. You are using a 2048 bit certificate. it cannot encrypt any data bigger than 256 bytes because it need to be smaller than RSA modulus in case no RSA padding is used. If RSA-OEAP padding is used, another 11 bytes will be used for padding.

In RSA encryption, you normally need to use [key encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_encapsulation) to support encryption of any arbitrary data sizes. In nutshell, it means that you need to encrypt you data with a random symmetric key and symmetric algorithm(like AES), and then encrypt its key using RSA and send both to other side. Other side first decrypt symmetric key, and then use it to decrypt original data. So it will be something like this:

```
Encryption side
-----------------
1- Generate random AES key
2- Encrypt data with AES and generated key
3- Encrypt Key with RSA public key
4- Send 2 encrypted data to the other side

Decryption side
-----------------
1- Split received data to encrypted key and encrypted data
1- Decrypt AES Key with RSA private key
2- Decrypt data with AES and decrypted AES key
```

In addition, read comment on this answer for further reading about padding and in detail implementations.

Comment: Combining RSA with AES the way you describe is called "hybrid encryption".

Comment: @Robert hm...I think using key encapsulation is best.... :D

Comment: Actually for PKCS1-v1.5 padding, which is what Java's `PKCS1Padding` is, the limit is 11 bytes less than the modulus size, here 247 bytes. And the OP's data is only 12 bytes, far under the limit. While hybrid encryption is better in general, it isn't needed for this Q.

Comment: Lots of missing points like padding. If there is no padding then cube-root attack will work. Therefore RSA-KEM uses random than a KDF. See [Is direct RSA encryption of AES keys secure?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76857/18298) . And note that RSA-KEM is vulnerable to Hastad. Use RSA-OAEP...

Comment: @kelalaka true. but my answer was for general knowledge, not in detail implementation really.